# c# pushing to database REALLY slow

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, sqlcommand

I'm making a folder/text file reader in one. the obtained data should be pushed to a SQL server. However it's going really, really.. slow.

Really slow =>

data that needs to be inserted:

2.73 GB (2,938,952,122 bytes)

spread over

78,995 Files, 5,908 Folders

with a folder structure of

Folder (toplevel)

- Folder

  - Folder

    1. Textfiles
    2. ...
  - more folders -> 100 maybe
- Folder

  - Folder

    1. Textfiles
    2. ..
    3. ..
- 60 folders total

  - ...

    1. ...

I've been reading them for like 3 days or smth

Also because the files contain a lot of duplicate values I think it's slow too

**Reasons I think it is happening:**

1. Because i have a relational database I need to keep opening a new connection
2. nested foreach

   - Is there a way to increase this dramatic performance?
   - Should i use SQLbatchcopy instead? Can you even use it for a relation table because all examples I see are with just one table getting filled, ignoring foreign key's that need to be inserted (my get get generated by auto increment in SQL db)
   - Is there maybe even another solution to this that would make this a lot easier?

Source code:

```
  static void leesTxt(string rapport, string TreinNaam)
                    {
                        foreach (string textFilePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(rapport, "*.txt"))
                        {

                            string textname = Path.GetFileName(textFilePath);
                            textname = textname.Substring(0, textname.Length - 4);
                            List<string> variablen = new List<string>();


                            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(textFilePath))
                            {
                                for (int x = 0; x <= 10; x++)
                                    r.ReadLine();

                                string output;

                                while (true)
                                {

                                    output = r.ReadLine();
                                    if (output == null)
                                        break;

                                    if (Regex.IsMatch(output, @"^\d"))
                                    {
                                            variablen.Clear();
                                            string[] info = output.Split(' ');
                                            int kolom = 6;
                                            datum = info[0];





                                        string[] datumTijdelijk = datum.Split(new[] { '/' });

                                        try
                                        {
                                            datum = string.Format("{2}/{1}/{0}", 
                                        }
                                        catch
                                        {
                                            datum = "0002/02/02";
                                        }


                                        try
                                        {
                                            tijd = info[1];
                                        }
                                        catch
                                        {
                                            Debug.WriteLine(tijd);
                                            tijd = "00:00:00.000";
                                        }
                                        try
                                        {
                                            foutcode = info[2];
                                            absentOfPresent = info[4];
                                            teller = info[5];
                                            omschrijving = info[6];
                                        }
                                        catch
                                        {

                                        }


                                        while (kolom < info.Count() - 1)
                                        {
                                            kolom++;
                                            omschrijving = omschrijving + " " + info[kolom];
                                        }
                                        PushFoutenToSQLdb(datum, tijd, foutcode, textname, omschrijving, teller, absentOfPresent, TreinNaam);
                                    }
                                    if (output == string.Empty)
                                    {
                                        output = " ";
                                    }
                                    if (Char.IsLetter(output[0]))
                                    {
                                        if (variablen.Contains(output))
                                            output = output + "*";

                                        try
                                        {
                                            PushExtraInfoToSQLdb(output, datum, tijd, foutcode, textname, teller, absentOfPresent, omschrijving, TreinNaam);
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception ex)
                                        {
                                        }

                                        variablen.Add(output);
                                    }

                                }



                               }  
static void PushExtraInfoToSQLdb(string waarde, string datum, string tijd, string foutcode, string module, string teller, string Mnemo, string omschrijving, string treinNaam)
                {
                    myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Events].[dbo].[ExtraInfo] (Value,FoutId) Values (@waarde,(SELECT FoutId from [Events].[dbo].[Fouten] WHERE Datum = @datum AND Time = @tijd AND FoutCode = @foutcode AND TreinId = (SELECT TreinId from [Events].[dbo].[Treinen] WHERE Name = @treinNaam)))", myConnection);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@waarde", waarde);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datum", datum);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tijd", tijd);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foutcode", foutcode);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@module", module);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teller", teller);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mnemo", Mnemo);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@omschrijving", omschrijving);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@treinNaam", treinNaam);


                    try
                    {
                        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }

                } 
static void PushFoutenToSQLdb(string datum, string tijd, string foutcode, string module, string omschrijving, string teller, string absentPresent, string treinNaam)
                    {
                        myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Events].[dbo].[Fouten]  (Datum ,FoutCode, Omschrijving, Module,Time,Teller,Mnemo, TreinId)  Values (@datum , @foutcode, @omschrijving, @module, @tijd, @teller, @absentPresent ,(SELECT TreinId from [Events].[dbo].[Treinen] WHERE Name = @treinNaam))", myConnection);
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datum", datum);
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tijd", tijd);
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foutcode", foutcode);
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@module", module);
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teller", teller);
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@omschrijving", omschrijving);
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@absentPresent", absentPresent);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@treinNaam", treinNaam);

                    try
                    {
                        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Yes, Try combining your insert statement into one (i.e. insert into table values (a, b, c), (d, e, f) instead of executing a query on each loop

Comment: Start learning how to use a profiler. Really. And define "really really slow".

Comment: @TomTom I think it's not much to do with SQL Profiler, he has problems inside the loop but not the query itself.

Comment: Interacting with a database one row at a time has an acronym - RBAR ; Row By Agonising Row.  In short, don't do it.  A good search term is "BULK LOAD", from which you should find various methods of pushing many rows to the database in a single action; some general across many different RDBMS, some specific to MS SQL Server.

Comment: Yes and no. If you load 10mb text files, then "row by row" will not make it that much slower. Even row by row - the question is how bad it is. And I never said SQL profiler. I meant .NET profiler.

Comment: How many rows do you expect to be written to those two tables?

Comment: One table contains already 2.396.195 rows the second table which contains detailed values about the first one problably like 8x the first table size, EDIT: 22.926.049

Comment: Silly question: is there enough band width between you and the server?

Comment: I'm aware of that, but how do you obtain your foreign key? and link tables together? any good tutorial for that somewhere, all examples I find are only bulking one table and not a relationship between 2

Comment: Another not-so-silly question: Did you make sure your target db is already sized for the data to be inserted? If your SQL Server is constantly busy increasing the size your performance is degraded. Setting the db Recovery Mode to "Simple" is also advisable.

Answer (score 1):

As these are all inserts, and as everyone has pointed out, doing a line by line insert is not a good approach. Check out the [SqlBulkCopy Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx). This is designed to write batch/bulk inserts to the database directly from your code with performance in mind.

Excerpt from the documentation.

> Microsoft SQL Server includes a popular command-prompt utility named bcp for moving data from one table to another, whether on a single server or between servers. The SqlBulkCopy class lets you write managed code solutions that provide similar functionality. **There are other ways to load data into a SQL Server table (INSERT statements, for example), but SqlBulkCopy offers a significant performance advantage over them.**

Your best approach (*because your data is coming from text file(s)*) is probably to create an in memory `DataTable` in which you then define a schema that matches your database schema. You then populate this table with the data you want to insert and call the `WriteToServer` method and pass in the table.

As the `SqlBulkCopy` only supports writing to 1 table per instance you will have to execute this 2 times, once for your `Fouten` table and once for your `ExtraInfo` table. You will also have to pull in some of the information before hand as you are using `SELECT` statements in your existing `INSERT` statements, this can then be used to populate the `DataTable` before you pass it to the `SqlBulkCopy` instance. `SqlBulkCopy` also does not work with `Transactions` so you will have to sanatize your data before you insert it as you have no easy way to roll everything back if there is a validation error on one or more records.

### Pseudo code

1. Create an in memory Dictionary of key = `TreinId` and value = `Name` and populate it from your existing data using a `DataReader`.
2. Create a DataTable for `Fouten` that matches the `Fouten` table schema
3. Populate the table with your data from the text file and use the Dictionary created in step 1 for `TreinId`
4. Call `SqlBulkCopy`, upload your data
5. Create an in memory Dictionary of key = Date+Time+FoutCode+TreinNaam, value = FoutId, populate this from your existing (new) data using a `DataReader`. *seems like this is somewhat conveluted, maybe there is a better way to define this lookup?*
6. Populate the `ExtraInfo` table with your data from the text file and use the Dictionary created in step 5 for the FK value back to `Fouten`
7. Call `SqlBulkCopy`, upload your data

### Other Considerations for your Existing structure

1. Run [Sql Server Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx) and see if there are other factors that are contributing to the slow inserts that you are not aware of (*for example a not tuned SELECT statement in your INSERT*). If you see that a single insert statement as you have it defined is very expensive then doing the above `SqlBulkCopy` has almost 0 impact.
2. Your tables are large as you indicated in your comments. In your INSERT statements, which you are doing 1 at a time, you are also doing a SELECT for each statement. If your indexes are not properly defined you could be executing a table scan for each SELECT in each insert. This would lead to a huge performance loss. Best fix here:

   1. Remove the select from the INSERT by caching the possible list of values in memory in a Dictionary. Use a DataReader to accomplish this.
   2. Tune the Indexes to ensure that they are being used in the `SELECT` part of your `INSERT` statements.
3. Make sure that your data defined in your INSERT command matches exactly the data types in your schema. Example: if you have an NVARCHAR column but define the type as VARCHAR it could take longer, or having an BIGINT in the database but passing an Int32 from code could take longer because these have to be converted.
4. Make sure your tables do not have indexes or statistics which are expensive to update with every UPDATE operation you execute. You could disable them and then rebuild once you are done if this is causing problems.
5. Check the Auto growth settings on the database and the amount of space reserved for the LOG (also the data file). The default used to be 10MB and with a large database to increment by only 10MB if you are out of space is expensive and would happen frequently with a large number of INSERTS. Here you should increase the size of the data files. This also reduces fragmentation on disk. See [Considerations for the "autogrow" and "autoshrink" settings in SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315512) for more info.
6. Check for triggers on your tables. If you have insert triggers these could lead to significant performance degradation.

Comment: But how do you obtain the foreign key id then? the datatable doesnt know what data is in the SQL database already or does it? because that column needs to be populated or the point of the relation database is gone.

Comment: @Goostrabha - i have updated the answer with some Pseudo code outlining the steps to go about doing this.

Comment: @Goostrabha - see also the latest other considerations I have added. You should investigate these first because if there are problems here then you won't see any benefit in using the `SqlBulkCopy` class.

Comment: Thanks for these efforts..! Much appreciated

Comment: @Goostrabha - `graag gedaan` / glad to help :). Let us know how it turns out.

Comment: Might it be wise to just turn the auto increment off of the foreign key's in SQL? And insert them generated by c#? that way i could decide the key on the go while using SQLbatchCopy instead needing to retrieve it. If yes, how should i make the key look like, make it match my unique contraint? or does it take too much data?

Comment: @Goostrabha - that is a good idea assuming that all new `ExtraInfo` records are related only the new `Fouten` records. [Here is a good link](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/24-turning-off-and-on-identity-column-in-sql-server.htm) to do this. You should make sure that there are no other processes also pushing new data to the table. You only need to do it on the parent table `Fouten` and you need to get the greatest id the table has so far `SELECT MAX(FoutId) FROM Fouten` and start incrementing **after** that point (+1 for each record).